# Passing TransactionScope to tasks created by Parallel.Invoke

Tags: c#, .net, transactions, transactionscope, task-parallel-library

I want the `TxJobs`, which are running in parallel, to create a scope from this parent transaction. How do I make this work?

```
using (var tx = TransactionScope()) {
    Parallel.Invoke(TxJob1, TxJob2) ;
    tx.Complete();
}
```

I passed in a `DependentClone`:

```
using (var tx = new TransactionScope()) {
    var dtx1 = Transaction.Current.DependentClone(
        DependentCloneOption.RollbackIfNotComplete) ;
    var dtx2 = Transaction.Current.DependentClone(
        DependentCloneOption.RollbackIfNotComplete) ;
    Parallel.Invoke(() => TxJob1(dtx1), () => TxJob2(dtx2)) ;
    tx.Complete();
}
```

In the `TxJob1` and `TxJob2` methods, it works if I just call `Complete` on the `DependentClones`. However, if I create a scope from the clone I get a `TransactionAbortedException`:

```
void TxJob1(Transaction dt) {
    using (var tx = new TransactionScope(dt)) {
        Console.WriteLine(dtx.TransactionInformation.LocalIdentifier);
        tx.Complete();
    }
}
```

The exception is raised by the call to `Complete` in the main method, not in `TxJobs`. Why does this fail?

[edit] If I explicitly call Complete on the DependentTransaction in TxJobs, then it works. If I don't call Complete on the new TransactionScope in TxJobs (triggering a rollback), then the parent transaction fails. It looks like I have to call Complete on both Transaction objects.

Comment: Have you tried using the `DependentCloneOption.BlockCommitUntilComplete` option?  Even though `Parallel.Invoke` will block until all parallel tasks are completed, you really want the parent `Transaction` to wait on the children to complete, not have the children abort if `Complete` is called on the parent before the children do (which is what `DependentCloneOption.RollbackIfNotComplete` does).

Comment: @casperOne: Yes, with `BlockCommitUntilComplete` the code blocks on the main method's call to `Complete()` and, after a while, times out and throws a `TransactionAbortedException`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like I have to call Complete on both the dependent clone and the TransactionScope. MS does the same in their [sample code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transaction.dependentclone.aspx).